# How do I tell my test to wait for a callback in a goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am using the dockerclient https://github.com/samalba/dockerclient which has a channel-based API to listen for events `client.MonitorEvents()` and a convenient callback method `client.StartMonitorEvents(callbackHandler)`.

I want to test that the handler gets called. Of course, the dockerclient handles the events in a goroutine.

For now, my handler just spits out a log. If I wait in my test, everything is handled. If I do not, it exits before it handles anything:

```
func eventCallback(event *dockerclient.Event, ec chan error, args ...interface{}) {
  log.Printf("Received event: %#v\n", *event)
}
```

My test seems straightforward:

```
func TestReceiveEvent(t *testing.T) {
   createAndMonitorEvents(server.URL)
   <- eventReady
   eventWriter.Write([]byte(someEvent))
   // test for something here
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work unless I put in a `time.Sleep()` because of the goroutine.

How do I tell my test, "wait for the other routine to do its work before running the test", other than putting in some arbitrary sleep? I am looking to test that the event is processed correctly by my handler.

The alternate interface, `client.MonitorEvents()` returns a channel, which gives me greater control, but the receive off the channel spits out infinite `nil` events.

UPDATE:

As requested, createAndMonitorEvents is:

```
func createAndMonitorEvents(url string) {
  // Init the client
  docker, _ := dockerclient.NewDockerClient(url, nil)

  // Listen to events
  stopchan := make(chan struct{})

  go func() {
    eventErrChan, err := docker.MonitorEvents(nil, stopchan)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    for e := range eventErrChan {
        if e.Error != nil {
            return
        }
        eventCallback(&e.Event, nil)
    }
    fmt.Println("monitor in place")
  }()
}
```

Comment: what is `createAndMonitorEvents`?

Comment: Just a routine called by my `main()` to create the dockerclient and monitor the events. I will update the q.

Comment: So it is just a listener for events that calls the handler. No big deal. My question is how to get the test to wait to make sure the event is handled properly.

Comment: Substantially changed my answer -- I think you can use `MonitorEvents`, and the `nil`s you're seeing are just the symptom of a closed channel (which you can handle a couple ways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you get `nil`s with `MonitorEvents`, you're just seeing that the event channel is closed (the [source of `MonitorEvents`](https://github.com/samalba/dockerclient/blob/master/dockerclient.go#L315) includes a `close(eventOrErrorChan)`, supporting this). `evt, ok := <-c` lets you directly check if that (`ok` will be false when it's closed), and `for evt := range c` will stop after it's closed. In general, receiving from a closed channel is [specified](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) to "[yield] the element type's zero value after any previously sent values have been received"

On the question about waiting on a callback: the callback can close a channel. (Or send to it.) Then your test can wait up to a specified length of time with a `select`:

```
select {
case <-c:
        /* ...success... */
case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
        /* timed out */
}
```

If you know some error conditions cause the handler not to finish, or not to run, it could signal those situations on a different channel, or by sending a different value to `c`.

Comment: Aha! Now I understand the `nil`s I have been seeing. I missed that part of the spec, thank you for pointing it out. I still don't get how this answers the q, though. How do I tell my test, "wait for the callback handler to respond"? Either way, +1 for catching that on the channel.

Comment: You can make a callback write to (or close) a channel, then wait on the channel. In other words, you could build something a bit like `MonitorEvents` on top of the callback interface. (Though that's not how I was thinking of it at the time--I hadn't yet looked at `MonitorEvents` when I suggested that.)

Comment: "something a bit like `MonitorEvents` on the callback interface." Meaning that I could have my tests monitor the original callback code to check it gets called?

Comment: You could write the callback so it closes a channel, and test code can receive from the channel to wait on it. I'm not sure whether the callback you're taking about is part of your test code or part of the application being tested. If the callback lives in the app, you may need to tweak your app so it accepts a channel that, if non-nil, the caller can use to wait for the callback to run. (Not that different from many other sorts of changes people make to apps to make them testability.)

Comment: It is part of the app... that is what the other answer said. I already do something sort of like that to know when a different section of code (in my test) has executed so I can send information.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help

> A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish. The main goroutine calls Add to set the number of goroutines to wait for. Then each of the goroutines runs and calls Done when finished. At the same time, Wait can be used to block until all goroutines have finished.

http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup

Comment: A channel is a better fit here than a wait group.

Comment: The WaitGroup is a pretty cool idea in general, but I have no way of getting to it. It would require knowing which routine in the code.

Answer (score 0):

"How do I tell my test, "wait for the other routine to do its work before running the test", other than putting in some arbitrary sleep?"

You either send on a channel or close one. Where the caller is receiving execution blocks until a signal occurs. I don't really see how to work your code into something that makes sense though... You can't allocate the stop channel in the function, you have to pass it to the function so the caller can listen on it. Like how does this even compile?

```
func TestReceiveEvent(t *testing.T) {
   createAndMonitorEvents(server.URL)
   <- eventReady // undeclared variable, and discarding the event you recieved?
   eventWriter.Write([]byte(someEvent)) //and another variable that is not declared
   // test for something here
}
```

Maybe and idea that will help get you started...

```
func createAndMonitorEvents(url string, done chan bool) {
      //the codes
      close(done)
}


func TestReceiveEvent(t *testing.T) {
  eventReady := make(chan bool)
    createAndMonitorEvents(server.URL, eventReady)
    <- eventReady
    eventWriter.Write([]byte(someEvent)) // dis still don't exist though
    // test for something here
```

}

Comment: So you are saying, basically, the only ways are to play with a timer, or have a function that explicitly says, "I am done." Is that it? Fortunately, I control the source code for the function (I am testing my own stuff), so that helps.